# How do I get the contents of cell that has a formula on another worksheet based on values from the 2 sheets matching

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to get the contents of a cell from `WS1` to display in `WS2`.  To get the right cell location I am comparing a range of values from `WS1` to a single value in `WS2`.  (see pictures attached)

I need to show the value from `WS1` in Column `A` in `WS2` Column `E`.  To get the right row, I need `WS2` `C` value to match the first `WS1` `D` value.  The formula I have is as follows - but it isn't working:

```
=CELL("contents", INDEX(ws1!a1:a6, MATCH(ws2!c2, ws1!d2:d10, 0), 1))
```

WS1: [image: WS1]
WS2: [image: WS2]

Comment: I don't think the columns in your description are matching up to your pictures. Or maybe I'm just very confused.

Comment: sorry about that - they don't

Comment: I am comparing the WS1 col E to WS2 col E to find the right row i need to grab the value from WS1 col B